# Implement ProFTPd server without chroot

Tags: ftp, chroot, proftpd

Can I use ProFTPd without using a `chroot` jail (thereby preventing access to anything outside of the FTP root)? I have a requirement to have symlinks in my FTP source that point to locations outside of the directory where I root my FTP service.

All of the docs and discussion I've read on ProFTPd talk about how to use the chroot functionality (even [within StackExchange](https://askubuntu.com/a/32037/39012)), but I'm wondering if I can bypass using that and use a different method to serve my FTP root. Since the symlinks must remain as symlinks, mounting the directories as a way of bypassing the chroot restriction (the clever "solution" to the problem) does not work.

Comment: This link here : http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html will give you what you need, especially the "Filesystem tricks" section.

Comment: Again, I need to completely bypass the **chroot** functionality.

Comment: That need is motivated solely by the symlinks issue or is there something else? If the symlinks are the only problem, the link I posted is valid.

Comment: The suggestions in the **chroot** documentation cause the filesystem to treat the mounts as actual directories. My filesystem contains symlinks that should remain as symlinks, so that solution does not suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProFTPD has the [**mod_vroot** module](http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_vroot.html) for this purpose. You can compile this module into ProFTPD yourself or install it if your repositories have it (`apt-get install proftpd-mod-vroot` for certain Debian repositories).

**mod_vroot** allows a user to configure a "virtual chroot", setting the *DefaultRoot* directive (the initial/root directory for a session; ProFTPD would chroot to this directory without **mod_vroot**), but allowing symbolic links to point outside of the *DefaultRoot* path. mod_vroot also supports the *VRootServerRoot* directive, to which ProFTPD will perform a real chroot, meaning that symlinks can point outside of the *DefaultRoot*, but must target locations within the *VRootServerRoot* path.

Example config:

```
<IfModule mod_vroot.c>
    VRootEngine on

    VRootServerRoot /usr/share/ # Symlinks can only point to location within /usr/share/
    VRootOptions allowSymlinks
    DefaultRoot /usr/share/ftproot/
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have had problems implementing this with certain distributions ([Raspbian](http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=65994)).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that FTP was defined in the earliest prehistory of the Internet, and so has *no* provisons for security (passwords in plain text, ...). That is why FTP servers are usually used only for anonymous login, and as it is open to the Internet and has a rich command set (and a lot of very surprising functionality, this was created to transfer files between machines with *really* bizarre architectures, differing character representations, and strange operating systems). For sanity one runs such beasts clamped down.

Is it an option to use something like scp(1)? Use a webserver instead (should even be more efficient)?

Why do the symbolic links have to be symbolic links?

Comment: Other programs are accessing the filesystem in a way where they may want to ignore the symlinks. The FTP server should not ignore the symlinks.

Comment: I know that Pure-FTPd can accomplish my requirements, but I was wondering about ProFTPd specifically.

Comment: @palswim, are hard links out of the question? Place the files in the FTP area and link to them from outside? Keep copies inside?

Comment: @vonbrand hard links may be unusable if one needs to have links to other file systems.

Comment: @palswim you may use `mount --bind` as a workaround (will need to mount on every boot though)